# autoit Not getting random click on IE embedded version

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit

What I want is to to create IE embedded version and open mysite.com and open random links.

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
$width = 800
$height = 600
$hMain=GUICreate("TEST",800,600,@DesktopWidth/2-$width/2,@DesktopHeight/2-$height/2)
$oIE = ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")
$GUIActiveX = GUICtrlCreateObj ($oIE, 0, 0, $width+3, $height+2)
$oIE.navigate("www.mysite.com")
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumLinks = @extended
$oIE._IELinkClickByIndex($oIE, Random(0, $iNumLinks -1))
GUISetState()
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $msg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
    EndSwitch
    WinSetTitle($hMain,"",_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "title"))
WEnd
```

This is the code that **Milos** gave me to get all links from a site and open random link. It works fine when I work on IE but in IE embedded version, it doesn't... :(

```
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumLinks = @extended
_IELinkClickByIndex($oIE, Random(0, $iNumLinks))
```

so need help to make it work on IE embedded version too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, its fixed.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <IE.au3>

_IEErrorHandlerRegister()

$width = 800
$height = 600

Local $oIE = _IECreateEmbedded()
$hMain=GUICreate("TEST",800,600,@DesktopWidth/2-$width/2,@DesktopHeight/2-$height/2, _
        $WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW + $WS_VISIBLE + $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS + $WS_CLIPCHILDREN)
GUICtrlCreateObj($oIE, 0, 0, $width+3, $height+20)

GUISetState() ;Show GUI

_IENavigate($oIE, "www.mysite.com")

Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumLinks = @extended
_IELinkClickByIndex($oIE, Random(0, $iNumLinks -1))
GUISetState()
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $msg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
    EndSwitch
    WinSetTitle($hMain,"",_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "title"))
WEnd
```

Comment: ok..I understand..why HTML5 not playing !! embedded IE is v7 :(

[link](http://i.gyazo.com/4a1cbae27eaa2cd1bfd2dc95a9c3750f.png)

Comment: problem solved... :) regkey entry :)

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/144996-iecreateembedded-embed-old-ie-version-7-when-9-is-installed-please-help-thanks/

Comment: What exactly was the problem? It would be much more useful if people wouldn't have to compare both scripts to find the difference.